# while filling information of login page in database table following error occurs

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: `System.NullReferenceException`: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Source Error: 


Line 17:     {
Line 18:         SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=class;Integrated Security=True");
Line 19:         cnn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconnection "].ConnectionString;
Line 20:         cnn.Open();
Line 21:         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

Source File: c:\Users\VIJU\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Class\Default2.aspx.cs    Line: 19
```

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Default2.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\VIJU\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Class\Default2.aspx.cs:19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

Comment: Please add code of aspx file and your code behind file.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this line:

```
cnn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconnection "].ConnectionString
```

I'm betting sqlconnection does not exist, or is mis-spelled in your web.config.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with your connection string key name.
The correction is as follow:

```
cnn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconnection"].ConnectionString;
```